# doInTransaction method calls 3 times every try

Tags: spring, transactions

I use TransactionTemplate for managing db connections:

```
txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus txStatus) {
            try {
                ***********************
                List<Map<String, Object>> rows = dbConn.queryForList(sql, bindValues);
                *********************************

                    System.out.println(txStatus.toString());
                    System.out.println(txStatus.isNewTransaction());
                    System.out.println(txStatus.isRollbackOnly());
                }
            }catch (RuntimeException e) {
                txStatus.setRollbackOnly();
                System.out.println("*************"+e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
```

and this is the result of mine code:

```
create connection
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@37b60886
true
false
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@37b60886
true
false
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@37b60886
true
false
```

3 times method calls: why it could be?

Comment: Maybe you invoke the .method 3 times! Add an other print statement to check this.

Comment: What statements I should add?

Comment: A `system.out.println` statement before `txTemplate.execute`

Comment: I add System.out.println("before call");
  txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {      and see next result:  before call  *** 1
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@4fc8cd5c
false
false  ***** 2
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@4fc8cd5c
false
false   ****3
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@4fc8cd5c
false
false      THis means that I invoke the method only 1 time but execute( doInTransaction - invoked 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My println methods was in for cicle - this is why I've print 3 times.